# Ajax success function unable to access within custom function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How to access "mentorslist" varibale in same function. "mentorslist" is success of ajax call. But i'm unable to access it within mentors() function.

```
function mentors(){
    var mentorslist = '';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: <?php echo  '"'.base_url().'index.php/MentorList/'.'"'; ?>,
      data: { pagelimit: 1,json: "true" },
      success: function( msg ) 
      {
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
          var $mentor_list ="";  
          var mlist = '';
          jQuery.each( obj.resset, function( i, val ){
            mlist = mlist+'<option value="'+val.mentor_Id+'">'+val.Name+'</option>';
            $("#mlist").get(0).options[$("#mlist").get(0).options.length] = new Option(val.Name,val.mentor_Id);
          });
         mentorslist = mlist;   //Able to access here
        }
    }); 

    return mentorslist; // gives undefine error
}
```

See here mentorslist variable is setting into ajax success and trying to return that through custom function but it returns me undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because Ajax is asynchronous you have the variable value only when the success event is triggered. So you can define your own function to call on success:

```
        var mentorslist = '';

        function mentors(myCallBack) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "yourPHP",
                data: {pagelimit: 1, json: "true"},
                success: function(msg) {
                    myCallBack(msg);
                }
            });
        }

        mentors(function(msg) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
            var $mentor_list = "";
            var mlist = '';
            jQuery.each(obj.resset, function (i, val) {
                mlist = mlist + '<option value="' + val.mentor_Id + '">' + val.Name + '</option>';
                $("#mlist").get(0).options[$("#mlist").get(0).options.length] = new Option(val.Name, val.mentor_Id);
            });
            mentorslist = mlist;   //Able to access here
        });
```

In any case you may always set the async property of the ajax call to false in order to change the ajax call from async to a synchronus one:

```
      function mentors(){
            var mentorslist = '';
            $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                url: <?php echo  '"'.base_url().'index.php/MentorList/'.'"'; ?>,
            data: { pagelimit: 1,json: "true" },
            success: function( msg )
            {
                var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
                var $mentor_list ="";
                var mlist = '';
                jQuery.each( obj.resset, function( i, val ){
                    mlist = mlist+'<option value="'+val.mentor_Id+'">'+val.Name+'</option>';
                    $("#mlist").get(0).options[$("#mlist").get(0).options.length] = new Option(val.Name,val.mentor_Id);
                });
                mentorslist = mlist;   //Able to access here
            }
        });
        return mentorslist;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

They are not in the same scope. You can't do that.

What you can do is set up a variable outside the function and set the value of it in the success of the ajax call. After that you can play with it.

Also make the ajax call sync so that when its done your script will continue.

```
mentorlist;
function mentors(){
    mentorslist = '';
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: <?php echo  '"'.base_url().'index.php/MentorList/'.'"'; ?>,
      data: { pagelimit: 1,json: "true" },
      success: function( msg ) 
      {
          var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);
          var $mentor_list ="";  
          var mlist = '';
          jQuery.each( obj.resset, function( i, val ){
              mlist = mlist+'<option value="'+val.mentor_Id+'">'+val.Name+'</option>';
              $("#mlist").get(0).options[$("#mlist").get(0).options.length] = new Option(val.Name,val.mentor_Id);
          });
     mentorslist = mlist;   //Able to access here
     }
    }); 
}

function asd()
{
    console.log(mentorlist);
}

mentors();
asd();
```

Comment: can you share script ?

Comment: I set up "mentorslist" variable outside function but still not working it.